# Recorrer Array de Ojetos con js y jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Quiero recorrer el siguiente JSON

```
{  
   "hdd":  
   [  
        {  
            "hdd_id": "2",  
            "hdd_id_comp": "6",  

        }  
    ],  
    "ram": [  
        {  
            "ram_id": "730",  
            "ram_id_comp": "6",  

        },  
        {  
            "ram_id": "742",  
            "ram_id_comp": "6",  

        },  
        {  
            "ram_id": "756",  
            "ram_id_comp": "6",  

        }  
    ]
}
```

Este JSON lo recibo de una API con php, y la aplicacion que lo recive es con html y jQuery. En si, lo que quiero es recibir el json y dividirlo para mostrarlo en tablas. Otro detalle que tengo es que cuando me el JSON lo tengo en una variable y lo mando a imprimir en la terminal de depuración, me manda que en conjunto es un array pero cada nivel son objetos.
Ya lo he tratado de recorrer de la siguiente forma.

```
 $.each(data.ram, function(i, item) {     
     html += '<tr>'+              
             '<td>' + item.hdd_id+'</td>'+
             '<td>' + item.hdd_id_comp + '</td>' +
             '</tr>';
   });
```

Cualquier ayuda sera de mucha utilidad.

Comment: No entiendo que quieres hacer realmente, en tu código ya estas recorriendo el JSON y añadiendo los valores a una estructura de tabla

Comment: ¿Quisieras generar y mostrar los "hdd" y "ram" en distintas tablas?

Comment: Si, efectivamente, Marcos lo que pasa es que no me los pinta en la pantalla  en un tabla.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías generar y mostrar los "hdd" y "ram" en distintas tablas de la siguiente forma:

```js
let json = {
  "hdd": [{
    "hdd_id": "2", "hdd_id_comp": "6"
  }],
  "ram": [{
    "ram_id": "730", "ram_id_comp": "6"
  }, {
    "ram_id": "742", "ram_id_comp": "6"
  }, {
    "ram_id": "756", "ram_id_comp": "6"
  }]
}

let html = '';

// Obtenemos las claves del objeto (eg: hdd y ram)
Object.keys(json).forEach(type => {
  // Por cada tipo creamos una tabla
  html += `<table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">${type}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>COMP ID</td>
    </tr>`;
  // Por cada elemento en el tipo
  json[type].forEach(product => {
    // Agregamos una fila a la tabla
    html += `
      <tr>
        <td>${product[type + '_id']}</td>
        <td>${product[type + '_id_comp']}</td>
      </tr>`;
  });
  // Cerramos la tabla
  html += `</table>`;
});

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html;
```

```css
table,
table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos. Es invaluable esta ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una forma sencilla de iterar el objeto y acceder a sus valores:

```
var json = {  
    "hdd": [ { "hdd_id": "2", "hdd_id_comp": "6" } ],  
    "ram": [  
        { "ram_id": "730", "ram_id_comp": "6" },  
        { "ram_id": "742", "ram_id_comp": "6" },  
        { "ram_id": "756", "ram_id_comp": "6" }  
    ]
}

// los items representan el key del object ( hdd, ram )
for ( item in json ) {

    // para acceder al valor de cada object 
    // js acepta el acceso al object como si fuese array
    console.log( json[ item ] );

    // para iterar sobre cada value del object 
    // para desplegar solo son items de ram por ejemplo
    if ( item == 'ram') {
        let row = json[ item ].map( x => {
            return `<tr>
                <td> ${x[ 'ram_id' ]} </td>
            </tr>
            `;
        });

        // la tabla donde los vas a mostrar
        $("#table tbody").append( row );
    }
}
```

Te invito a leer un poco sobre ES6 que es un estandar para escribir js. Saludos